# ajax response strips multidimensional array and unable to decode

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, json

I am using the `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` in localize script I am passing a big multidimensional array( it's big!). It works without any JSON encode, decodes. But I want to encode it is while I make ajax call...so I used
`json_encode` in localizing script (wp_json_encode also gives the same output).. I pass it through ajax data parameter.
now when I access that as 
`json_decode($_POST['largejson'], true)`
 i get the response but not as an array but a string with lot of backslashes
 `\":[{\"field_type\":\"shortcode_elementor_pro\",\"_id`

what could be possibly going wrong?

update i use this to debug it

```
if ($data_settings === null){
        switch (json_last_error()) {
          case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
              echo ' - No errors';
          break;
          case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
              echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
          break;
          case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
              echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
          break;
          case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
              echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
          break;
          case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
              echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
          break;
          case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
              echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
          break;
          default:
              echo ' - Unknown error';
          break;
          }
```

it showed - Syntax error, malformed JSON'; so json_encode might be the problem maker

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue
$set = stripslashes($set);